# Is there a way to make a implication graph of the following expression?

Tags: time-complexity, 2-sat

Is there a way to make implication graph of expression of form :

$$ ((x_1 \lor x_2)\lor(x_3 \lor x_2))\land(x_3 \lor x_4)$$

I haven't been able to find any sort of text on this and the usual way to make implication graph like of 2-SAT doesn't really make sense because of the extra OR in between.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/157149/755, https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/52423/5038.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Comment: Are you sure that your formula is correct? You can simplify your formula to $(x_1 \lor x_2 \lor x_3) \land (x_3 \lor x_4)$. You need to convert this formula to 2-CNF before you create the implication graph.

Comment: Seems like its not possible yet to make an implicatin graph.

Comment: @Anuj It is impossible, because the formula is equivalent to $(x_1 \lor x_2 \lor x_3) \land (x_3 \lor x_4)$, it contains the subformula $x_1 \lor x_2 \lor x_3$, which cannot be expressed as 2-CNF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula $((x_1 \lor x_2) \lor (x_3 \lor x_2)) \land (x_3 \lor x_4)$ is equivalent to $(x_1 \lor x_2 \lor x_3) \land (x_3 \lor x_4)$. Notice that the last formula contains the subformula $(x_1 \lor x_2 \lor x_3)$. If we can convert this formula to a 2-CNF formula, then we are done (we can construct an implication graph of the original formula).

However, it is mathematically impossible to express $(x_1 \lor x_2 \lor x_3)$ as 2-CNF formula, see [this mathematical argument](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1563077/expressing-3sat-clause-as-a-2sat-formula).

Comment: Thanks for the answer and link.